# jquery: Flash messages

Tags: jquery, messagebox

With jQuery, how can I display a flash message at the top of the page in an easy way? Is there something built-in, or a plugin, or is it easy enough to do it yourself?

What I mean is like after a successful ajax post I would like to just say "hey, it went good" in a non-obtrusive way.

Comment: Added another option you can call from anywhere to my answer based on your comment. post a comment if you need something else

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would check out the [jQuery growl style plugins available](http://webtoolkit4.me/2009/08/13/jquery-growl-likenotification-systems/) if you're looking for something quick to implement :)

The [`.ajaxSuccess()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) would be a good place to run your code, or for errors [`.ajaxError()`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/), these are some of the [global ajax event handlers available](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/), for example:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  //fire success message using the plugin of choice, for example using gritter:
  $.gritter.add({ 
    title: 'Save Complete!',
    text: 'Your request completed successfully.'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 12):

I have used [Notify Bar](https://github.com/dknight/jQuery-Notify-bar) to do this also...  Really simple to use.

Answer (score 6):

No plugin needed try the following out.   It looks a lot like the one here on stackoverflow.  You can just pass the html to the function that you want to see

```
    showFlash: function (message) {
    jQuery('body').prepend('<div id="flash" style="display:none"></div>');
    jQuery('#flash').html(message);
    jQuery('#flash').toggleClass('cssClassHere');
    jQuery('#flash').slideDown('slow');
    jQuery('#flash').click(function () { $('#flash').toggle('highlight') });
},
```

Comment: But is there a way to access the content of the Rails `flash_notice` and plug it into `message`?

Answer (score 3):

It wont be worth using an extra plugin to do it.

What we do, is to **add a span to a predefined container** or **create an absolute positioned div** on ajax success and add ajax response message to it. You can further add a self destructive javascript or a "Clear" button in that div to remove it from DOM. JQuery has got good DOM handling capabilities.

As asked, here is one dirty example,

HTML

```
<div id="message_container" style="display:none">
  <span id="msg"></span>
  <a id="clear_ack" href="#" 
    onclick="$(this).parents('div#message_container').fadeOut(400); return false;">
    clear
  </a>
</div>
```

JS

```
var set_message = function(message){
     var container = $('#msg_container');
     $(container).find('span#msg').html(message);
     $(container).show();
}

var set_counter = function(){
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: '/some/url/',
           dataType: 'json',
           error: function(response){},
           success: function(response){
              if (responses.message){
                  set_message(responses.message)
              }
           }
       });
};
```

Comment: Could you give me some code example on how you would do this? Kind of new to jQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

I just added this to my page, displays a loading indicator for each ajax call (no matter where it is on the page)

```
/* Ajax methods */
/* show the message that data is loading on every ajax call */
var loadingMessage = 'Please wait loading data for page...';
$(function()
{
    $("#AjaxStatus")
    .bind("ajaxSend", function()
    {
        $(this).text(loadingMessage);
        $(this).show();
    })
    .bind("ajaxComplete", function()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

And the status:

```
<span id="AjaxStatus" class="ui-state-error-text"></span>
```

OK, based on your most recent comment, how about this option default message, or complex:

```
ShowStatus(true, 'Save Failed with unknown Error', 4000);

/* show message for interval */
var saveMessageText = 'Saving...';
function ShowStatus(saveMessage, message, timeInMilliseconds)
{
    var errorMessage = $("#Errorstatus");
    if (saveMessage)
    {
        errorMessage.show();
        var myInterval = window.setInterval(function()
        {
            message = message + '...';
            errorMessage.text(message);
            errorMessage.show();
        }, 1000);
        window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            clearInterval(myInterval);
            errorMessage.hide();
        }, timeInMilliseconds);
    }
    else
    {
        errorMessage.text(message);
        errorMessage.show();
        window.setTimeout('$("#Errorstatus").hide()', timeInMilliseconds);
    };
};
```

Snip from jquery ajax:

```
   success: function(msg)
    {
        ShowStatus(true, 'Hey it went well', 4000);
        Process(msg);
    },

  failure: function(msg)
    {
        ShowStatus(true, 'Save Failed with unknown Error', 4000);
    }
```

Comment: Have actually done the same thing, but using an animated icon. The message I am talking about isn't something to show while it goes on though, but a message that is in the answer I get back from a call.

Comment: Added a new section based on your comments. You can even call this as part of an ajax process with different messages during, on success and after.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something like this: http://projects.zoulcreations.com/jquery/growl/

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [jquery-notice](http://www.sandbox.timbenniks.com/projects/jquery-notice/), which is really simple and self-contained.  It's MIT licensed, just a zip file with the .js and .css files, and you can call it with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready( function () {
    jQuery.noticeAdd({
        text: '${flash_get()}',
        stay: true
        });
    return false;
    });
</script>
```

Though I also liked the solution from @Brian ONeal for [Notify Bar](https://github.com/dknight/jQuery-Notify-bar), that also looks very simple.

jquery-notice makes a box for each message on the upper right corner of the page.  Notify Bar pulls down from the top edge, and includes a few different styles for errors, regular, or success notices.

Answer (score -1):

There is not any built-in function for flash message in jquery but you can use `fadein()` and `fadeout()` for flash message with setting some time transition.